# Can't reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create SqlServer Backup and Restore  C# application.

I used below code.

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
    {
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS");
    Server server = new Server(con);
    Backup source = new Backup();
    source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    source.Database = "MyDataBaseName";
    BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
    source.Devices.Add(destination);
    source.SqlBackup(server);
    con.Disconnect();
    } 

public static void RestoreDatabase(string backUpFile)
    {
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS");
    Server server = new Server(con);
    Restore destination = new Restore();
    destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    destination.Database = "MyDataBaseName";
    BackupDeviceItem source = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
    destination.Devices.Add(source);
    destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    destination.SqlRestore(server);
    }
```

And then I tried to add below references

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo;
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended;
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo;

They are now in reference list.
But I could use only "***using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;***"
Other can't use.
Why is that?

I'm using VS8 Professional Edition.

and please let me know if there is any fault in above code.
If there is another good code than this that I can use for this process, please tell me

Please help me.

Comment: Your code looks ok
Do you have installed SQL server on your machine?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? For SQL 2008 and above, Microsoft provides something like DACPAC framework, which can be used to export dacpac(and bacpac), import dacpac(bacpac) and create back ups.

Comment: Yes Im using Microsfot Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: Do I need to download that DACPAC framework seperately and install it or it is coming with vs8 package. And how can i use this for my application.

Comment: yes, you will have to download and install the SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools). That will install the dac framework. I have done something similar but the code is on my office machine. Will get you tomorrow.

Comment: also if you can please send me a link where I can download this tool for vs8 professional edition. Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: But this SSDT available only for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Because I'm using visual studio 2008

Comment: Hi Yogendra, Im waiting for your sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.dac.dll`

Comment: I cant find it in in Assemblies. Do I need to download it and add. Where I can download this dll

Comment: you will have to download and install the Sql Server data tools (SSDT)

Comment: is this compatible with VS8 professional edition. Where I can download this?